# Looking for a few tutorials on switching views and cross-view communication

Tags: iphone

I'm looking for a few good tutorials or articles out there that might help me with communicating between different views which I have setup in a TabBarController.

I'd like to know how to properly call upon methods in other views of my TabBarController and then switch to that view.

The other thing I am curious about is how to launch views which are not part of the TabBarController.

I know these are simple questions, but for whatever reason I've been having real difficulty getting these simple tasks accomplished even after reading Apple's documentation.

Thanks in advance,
David

Answer (score 0):

Your questions are very broad and open-ended and, as such, will be difficult to answer specifically.  If you need specific answers to a specific problem, you'll have to describe the problem in detail (perhaps with code snippets) to help us answer you.

Basically, your question is: "How do I learn the fundamentals of the iOS view hierarchy and communication chain?", I am right?

I've told so many people this same thing, that I made a tinyurl for it -- one of the best books ever to get started and help people understand the basics of iOS, how things interlink, how to communicate between views, etc., [is this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430216263)

Beyond that, there are a number of forums specifically dedicated to iPhone tutorials.  In addition, if you're an iOS developer, you should have access to Apple's own video university (free!), and documentation (also free!) -- those are great places to start.

Good luck!